# How to preserve hyperlinks when appending row data with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, append, openpyxl

I'm trying to append a row from an excel sheet to another.
One of the cells has hyperlinked data but the append does not preserve the hyperlink, it only appends the plain data.
How do I preserve the hyperlink when appending?

```
if found==0: 
  data=[(RawData.cell(row=i,column=1).value, RawData.cell(row=i,column=2).value,RawData.cell(row=i,column=3).value,RawData.cell(row=i,column=4).value,RawData.cell(row=i,column=5).value)] 
for row in data: 
   CCBData.append(row) 

wb2 = load_workbook('./CR-Report_week_2018-40.xlsx') 
CCBData = wb2['Internal CCB'] 
wb2.save('CR-Report_week_2018-40.xlsx')
```

Raw data here : is an export from Client's JIRA with 4 columns: JIRA-ID-which is the hyperlinked text looks like NZK9090, title, Status and Creation time
This is an ever-increasing list of keys and need to be exported on a daily basis to check new incomings and old updated ones etc.

I now need this data exported on to my internal report which is the CR-Report_week_2018-40.xlsx,so i neeed to append new Ids that have come in and update the old existing ids.

i see that updating old IDs for status column etc has preserved the hyperlinking
but appending new IDs in the end, using the list method above has removed the hyperlink and only appended the plain JIRA ID text for the "key" column
updating the old IDs, doesnt actually write the value to the Key column, so not surprised that the hyperlink there is not lost

Comment: How did you read in your excel files?

Comment: here is the piece of the code i wrote:

Comment: if found==0:
        
        data=[(RawData.cell(row=i,column=1).value,
         RawData.cell(row=i,column=2).value,RawData.cell(row=i,column=3).value,RawData.cell(row=i,column=4).value,RawData.cell(row=i,column=5).value)]
        for row in data:

            
            CCBData.append(row)
            wb2 = load_workbook('./CR-Report_week_2018-40.xlsx')
            CCBData = wb2['Internal CCB']
                       
            wb2.save('CR-Report_week_2018-40.xlsx')

Comment: did i answer your question? to read the row from excel i used the lists (see data in the above code). and appended the rows at the end.one of these list values i have is a hyperlink, but i lose the hyperlink when the data gets appended at the end

Comment: Please edit your question to add information. Also, can you provide an example of your excel sheet content?

Comment: done , Please check the question if its making sense now

Comment: I've tried to format the code so it's at least readable but it stil doesn't really make sense. It looks incomplete. Though I suspect the problem is with the workbook itself.

Comment: could you leave a mail id.so that i can mail you the code and two workbooks. or can i post an attachment in here?

Comment: Found an answer! Hail Google :)! here is the answer for all those who might stumble on this :wb2.active['A'+str(CCBData.max_row)].hyperlink="https://jira.sdo.jlrmotor.com/browse/"+ RQID
                wb2.active['A'+str(CCBData.max_row)].value = RQID
                wb2.active['A'+str(CCBData.max_row)].style = "Hyperlink"